# Is it safe to delete an app insights that is associated with an Api Management Service?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-api-management, apim

I'm working for a client with lots of different teams where each one has different responsabilities and permissions.

One of the tasks I have is to delete an Application Insights resource.
That resource after investigation I found that it's getting use from an APIM (Api Management Service resource).

I found that some APIs have configured under "Settings tab" and under "Diagnostic Logs" that application insights I want to delete.

I already found a similar situation where an APIM API contains an app insights that is delete.

Later, with time I intend to make the change to configure those APIs to log into a different App Insights resource.

My question, is if it's completly safe to just delete the app insights resource?

Answer (score 0):

It is safe from non-monitoring functionality perspective. I.e., APIM will continue to work and will not result in outage.

It is not safe from monitoring perspective if the data in this Application Insights resource powers dashboards/alerts/etc.

Comment: This is good to know, I don't think it's powering any dashboard since it's an old app insights resource that should be deprecated.